# cakePHP routing help

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, url-routing

Here I am trying to route a page without showing its action in URL,

Eg: URL is `http://localhost/brands/1/xyz`

```
Router::connect(
    '/brands/:id/:name',
    array(
        'controller' => 'brands',
        'action' => 'index',
        'id' => '[0-9]{1,}',
        'name' => '[a-z]{1,}'
    )
);
```

it works fine....

But I need to make the `id` and `name` as optional and tried this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/brands/:id/:name',
    array(
        'controller' => 'brands',
        'action' => 'index',
        'id' => '[0-9]{1,}',
        'name' => '[a-z]{1,}'
    )
);
```

[according to http://book.cakephp.org/view/542/Defining-Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/542/Defining-Routes)

But when I try this URL `http://localhost/brands/1` it searches for action 1 but `http://localhost/brands/1/xyz` works fine.

Is there any mistake in my routing configuration????

Comment: Typically, by now someone with enough reputation would have stumbled on your question and fixed the formatting.  Regardless, I suggest you edit the question and format the code using the provided functionality to make your post more legible.  (Select the parts that are code and press the icon w/ the 1's and 0's, or press CTRL+K on your keyboard.)

Comment: Is id and name for the same brand? I mean, is the name used as a slug, to print a friendly name for the brand? In that case, name needs to be added to the url when you enter the url localhost/brands/1 (a bit more code to suggest in that case..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to be able to access the http://localhost/brands/1, you need to add this route:

```
Router::connect('/brands/:id',
   array('controller' => 'brands','action' => 'index','id' => '[0-9]{1,}')
);
```

(and also keep your original route)

```
Router::connect('/brands/:id/:name',
    array('controller' => 'brands','action' => 'index','id' => '[0-9]{1,}','name' => '[a-z]{1,}')
);
```

(and finally a route for /brands)

```
Router::connect('/brands',
    array('controller' => 'brands','action' => 'index')
);
```

Then check for $this->params['id'] and $this->params['name'] in the controller. If needed, redirect to the correct url (if the page is the same and you always want to have the the name in the url, which is good for SEO).

Comment: but the should be optional...if i route like this then when i try to access /brands/ will throw error........

Comment: Updated the answer. You need one additional route for accessing /brands.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a second route, omitting the optional parameters.